# Scraping multiple pages with an unchanging URL using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, infinite-scroll

I am using `Beautiful Soup` to extract data from a non-English website. Right now my code only extracts the first ten results from the keyword search. The website is designed so that additional results are accessed through the ‘more’ button (sort of like an infinity scroll, but you have to keep on clicking more to get the next set of results ). When I click ‘more’ the URL doesn’t change, so I cannot just iterate over a different URL each time.

I would really like some help with two things.

1. Modifying the code below so that I can get data from all of the pages and not just the first 10 results
2. Insert a timer function so that the server doesn’t block me

I’m adding a photo of what the ‘more’ button looks like because it’s not in English. It’s in blue text at the end of the [page](https://www.prothomalo.com/search?q=%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B7%E0%A6%A3).
[image]

```
import requests, csv, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import strftime, sleep

# make a GET request (requests.get("URL")) and store the response in a response object (req)
responsePA = requests.get('https://www.prothomalo.com/search?q=%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B7%E0%A6%A3')

# read the content of the server’s response
rawPagePA = responsePA.text

soupPA = BeautifulSoup(rawPagePA)
# take a look
print (soupPA.prettify())

urlsPA = [] #creating empty list to store URLs
for item in soupPA.find_all("div", class_= "customStoryCard9-m__story-data__2qgWb"): #first part of loop selects all items with class=field-title
    aTag = item.find("a") #extracting elements containing 'a' tags
    urlsPA.append(aTag.attrs["href"]) 

print(urlsPA) 

#Below I'm getting the data from each of the urls and storing them in a list
PAlist=[]
for link in urlsPA:
    specificpagePA=requests.get(link) #making a get request and stores the response in an object
    rawAddPagePA=specificpagePA.text # read the content of the server’s response
    PASoup2=BeautifulSoup(rawAddPagePA) # parse the response into an HTML tree
    PAcontent=PASoup2.find_all(class_=["story-element story-element-text", "time-social-share-wrapper storyPageMetaData-m__time-social-share-wrapper__2-RAX", "headline headline-type-9 story-headline bn-story-headline headline-m__headline__3vaq9 headline-m__headline-type-9__3gT8S", "contributor-name contributor-m__contributor-name__1-593"]) 
    #print(PAcontent)
    PAlist.append(PAcontent)
```

Comment: If you want to interact with the website you probably need selenium. Otherwise, maybe you can find what request is being sent when the button is pressed and emulate that.

Comment: I agree with @AlexNe. Pressing the more button in your browser doesn't change the html sent to your python script instead, it change the html in you browser. In order to "click the more button" in python, you will need to use selenium

Comment: here's the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Hah, found a tutorial: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need Selenium.

---

The Buttons sends the following GET-request:

```
https://www.prothomalo.com/api/v1/advanced-search?fields=headline,subheadline,slug,url,hero-image-s3-key,hero-image-caption,hero-image-metadata,first-published-at,last-published-at,alternative,published-at,authors,author-name,author-id,sections,story-template,metadata,tags,cards&offset=10&limit=6&q=ধর্ষণ
```

The important part is the "**offset=10&limit=6**" at the end, subsequent clicks on the button only increase that offset by 6.

Getting

> data from all of the pages

won't work, because there seem to be quite a lot and I don't see an option to determine how many. So you better pick a number and request until you have that many links.

As this request returns JSON, you also might be better off to just parse that instead of feeding the HTML to BeautifulSoup.

---

Have a look at that:

```
import requests
import json

s = requests.Session()
term = 'ধর্ষণ'
count = 20

# Make GET-Request
r = s.get(
    'https://www.prothomalo.com/api/v1/advanced-search',
    params={
        'offset': 0,
        'limit': count,
        'q': term
    }
)

# Read response text (a JSON file)
info = json.loads(r.text)

# Loop over items
urls = [item['url'] for item in info['items']]

print(urls)
```

This returns the following list:

```
['https://www.prothomalo.com/world/asia/পাকিস্তানে-সন্তানদের-সামনে-মাকে-ধর্ষণের-মামলায়-দুজনের-মৃত্যুদণ্ড', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/খাবার-দেওয়ার-কথা-বদলে-ধর্ষণ-অবসরপ্রাপ্ত-শিক্ষকের-বিরুদ্ধে-মামলা', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/জয়পুরহাটে-অপহরণ-ও-ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-যুবকের-যাবজ্জীবন-কারাদণ্ড', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/কিশোরীকে-ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-যুবক-গ্রেপ্তার', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/সুবর্ণচরে-এত-ধর্ষণ-কেন', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/১২-বছরের-ছেলেকে-ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-একজন-গ্রেপ্তার', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/ভালো-পাত্রের-সঙ্গে-বিয়ে-দেওয়ার-কথা-বলে-কিশোরীকে-ধর্ষণ-গ্রেপ্তার-১', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/সখীপুরে-দুই-শিশুকে-ধর্ষণ-মামলার-আসামিকে-গ্রেপ্তারের-দাবিতে-মানববন্ধন', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/বগুড়ায়-ছাত্রী-ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-তুফান-সরকারের-জামিন-বাতিল', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/world/india/ধর্ষণ-নিয়ে-মন্তব্যের-জের-ভারতের-প্রধান-বিচারপতির-পদত্যাগ-দাবি', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/ফুলগাজীতে-ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-অভিযুক্ত-ইউপি-চেয়ারম্যান-বরখাস্ত', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/ধুনটে-ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-ছাত্রলীগ-নেতা-গ্রেপ্তার', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/নোয়াখালীতে-কিশোরীকে-ধর্ষণ-ভিডিও-ধারণ-ও-অপহরণের-অভিযোগে-গ্রেপ্তার-২', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/বাবার-সঙ্গে-দেখা-করানোর-কথা-বলে-স্কুলছাত্রীকে-ধর্ষণ', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/opinion/column/ধর্ষণ-ঠেকাতে-প্রযুক্তির-ব্যবহার', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/world/asia/পার্লামেন্টের-মধ্যে-ধর্ষণ-প্রধানমন্ত্রীর-ক্ষমা-প্রার্থনা', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/তাবিজ-দেওয়ার-কথা-বলে-গৃহবধূকে-ধর্ষণ-কবিরাজ-আটক', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/আদালত-প্রাঙ্গণে-বিয়ে-করে-জামিন-পেলেন-ধর্ষণ-মামলার-আসামি', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/কিশোরীকে-দল-বেঁধে-ধর্ষণ-ও-ভিডিও-ধারণ-গ্রেপ্তার-৩', 'https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/ধর্ষণ-মামলায়-সহকারী-স্টেশনমাস্টার-গ্রেপ্তার']
```

By adjusting *count* you can set the number of urls (articles) to retrieve, *term* is the search-term.

The [**requests.Session**](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)-object is used to have consistent cookies.

---

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

---

**Edit:**

1. Just in case you are wondering how I found out which *GET*-request
   was being sent by clicking the button:   I went to the **Network
   Analysis**-tab from the developer tools of my browser (Firefox),
   clicked the button, observed which requests were being sent and
   copied that URL:

   [image: The sent request from the network-analysis tab]
2. Another explanation for the *params* parameter from the
   *.get*-function:   It contains (in python-dictionary-format) all the parameters that would normally be appended to the URL after the
   question mark.   So

   ```
   requests.get('https://www.prothomalo.com/search?q=%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B7%E0%A6%A3')
   ```

   can be written as

   ```
   requests.get('https://www.prothomalo.com/search', params={'q': 'ধর্ষণ'})
   ```

   which makes it a lot nicer to look at and you can actually see what
   you are searching for, because it's written in unicode and not
   already encoded for the URL.

---

**Edit**:
If the script starts returning an empty JSON-file and thus no URLs, you probably have to set a *User-Agent* like so (I used the one for Firefox, but any browser should be fine):

```
s.headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) '
                  'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'
})
```

Just put that code below the line where the session-object is initialized (the `s = ...` line).
A *User-Agent* tells the site what kind of program is accessing their data.

Always keep in mind that the server has other stuff to do as well and that the webpage has other priorities than sending thousands of search-results to a single person, so try to keep the traffic as low as possible. Scraping 5000 URLs is a lot and if you really *have* to do it multiple times, put a `sleep(...)` of at least a few seconds anywhere before you make the next request (not just to prevent getting blocked, but rather to be nice to the people who provide you with the information you request).
Where you put the sleep does not really matter, as the only time you're actually making contact with the server is the `s.get(...)` line.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful and the explanation is really easy to understand. The website gives the number of search results (5000 +) in a different language, so I guess I can just assign that value to count. I just had one more question- where in the code can I assign a function that delays the request, so that the server doesn't block me?

Comment: I edited my answer with additional information. That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you add selenium with bs4. To add the click for the site to load then get the page content.

you can download the geckodriver from [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Mock code will look like this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.prothomalo.com/search?q=%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B7%E0%A6%A3"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

# You need to iterate over this with a loop on how many times you want to click more, 
#do remember if it takes time to fetch the data try adding time.sleep() to wait for the page to load
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('{class-name}').click()

# Then you just get the page content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html')

# now you have the content loaded with beautifulsoap and can manipulate it as you were doing previously
{YOUR CODE}
```